# Mercure Hub server load - better solution

Tags: mercure

What is better solution taking into account server load (Mercure Hub)?

1. Users subscribe for one general topic so that Mercure Pushes information to all of them through this one topic and, based on some kind of ID in sent data, user endpoint decides if do something with it or not.
2. Or the better solution is to have unique topic for each element in the app? So that Mercure Hub handles and push data regarding this one particular topic to some amount of client endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you want to publish private (authorized) or public updates. Option 2 is the best when everything is public in my opinion because you can  put a wildcard in your JWT like:

```
{
    "mercure": {
        "subscribe": ["*"]
    }
}
```

But when using the private (authorized) mode, you can't specify every resource the user has access to in the JWT, because it would require a lot of database queries and your JWT will get too big probably.

So what i would do is the following;
Put the user resource as URL Template in the JWT like:

```
{
    "mercure": {
        "subscribe": ["/api/users/123/{?}"]
    }
}
```

The `{?}` means match anything. So `/api/blogs/1` doesn't match but `/api/users/123/blogs/1` does.
Now you'll only have to dispatch the update to the correct topics, this can be done by using `$blog->getSharedUsers()` for example by looping it and create topics like:

```
$topics = [];
foreach ($blog->getSharedUsers() as $user) {
    $topics[] = "/api/users/{$user->getId()}/blogs/{$blog->getId()}";  
}
```

I hope this helps, this is how i've done it in one of my SaaS apps.
If you have further questions feel free to ask, happy to help!

Comment: Thank you @Oliver I mean for public items. I was wondering what is more efficient. One topic for everything or contextual topics for each part of the website.